# quickest way to identify objects in array which have properties that are unique from properties in another object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, underscore.js, lodash

I have two arrays of data:

```
markerArray = [{
  properties: {id: 1}
},
{
  properties: {id: 2}
}];
```

and

```
data = [
 { id: 1},
 { id: 2},
 { id: 3}
]
```

I want to, as quickly as possible, create a new array of objects from `data` that have an id that does not exist in markerArray's `properties.id`

Lodash / underscore are an option.

Comment: Your question is full of conflicting statements. Please expand samples and show required result.

Comment: Sorry,you'll have to tell me what you find conflicting.

Comment: Your `markerArray` array is syntactically incorrect, it's missing a closing `}` bracket.

Comment: simplified question and fixed code error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest you map an array that just contains the ID's first:

```
var idArray= markerArray.map(function(item){
  return item.properties.id
});
//[1,2]
```

Then to find matches that *don't* exist in id array:

```
var result = data.filter(function(item){ 
      return idArray.indexOf(item.id) === -1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the fastest, but certainly the simplest is with lodash:

```
_.difference(_.pluck(data, "id"),
    _.pluck(_.pluck(markerArray, "properties"),"id"));
```

Comment: Just for the reference: this is much faster than using native array map or filter as shown in this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ypyv782f/

Comment: My console shows the ative version much faster here.

Comment: Looks like very browser dependent (like most benchmarks are). In Chrome, the Lo-dash version seems almost an order faster, where as marginally slower in Firefox and twice as fast in Safari from my basic tests. Not drawing conclusions, just sharing my observation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map` to map the IDs and then use `filter` to look into your `data` array:

```
var ids = markerArray.map(function(item) {
  return item.properties.id;
});

var result = data.filter(function(item) {
  return ids.indexOf(item.id) < 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a lodash solution:

```
_.reject(data, _.flow(
    _.identity,
    _.property('id'),
    _.partial(_.includes, _.map(markerArray, 'properties.id'))
));
```

Basically, you want to use [reject()](https://lodash.com/docs#reject) to remove the unwanted items from data (by creating a copy, not by modifying the original). We use [flow()](https://lodash.com/docs#flow) to build the callback function that decide which items are rejected. Here's the breakdown:

- Callback functions passed to `reject()` are given several arguments - we only care about the first one. This is what [identity()](https://lodash.com/docs#identity) does, it passes the first argument to the next function in `flow()`.
- The [property()](https://lodash.com/docs#property) function returns a new function. This new function will return the `id` property of the given item. Again, this `id` is input for the next `flow()` function.
- We then use [partial()](https://lodash.com/docs#partial) to do the actual filtering. The partially-applied argument is an array of IDs from the `markerArray`. The function we're creating a partial from is [includes()](https://lodash.com/docs#includes). If the id from `data` is in this array, we can remove it from the results.